# Geospatial search with mongo to determining which polygon a point in space is within?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a document that defines many Polygons. Suppose a user submits a point in space, How can I use mongo to determine which Polygon a user is within?

This image describes my query:

[image]

Comment: Read about [`$geoIntersects`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/). Does that sound like it fits your use case? The polygons would be stored in documents and you query for their intersection with the point.

Comment: $geoIntersects isn't the function... i am having a hard time finding a direct answer to this as well.